# LinqToSQL Not Updating the Database

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
// goal: update Address record identified by "id", with new data in "colVal"

string cstr = ConnectionApi.GetSqlConnectionString("SwDb"); // get connection str
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(cstr)) {
    Address addr = (from a in db.GetTable<Address>()
                    where a.Id == id
                    select a).Single<Address>();
    addr.AddressLine1 = colValue.Trim();
    db.SubmitChanges(); // this seems to have no effect!!!
}
```

In the debugger, addr has all the current values from the db table, and I can verify that AddressLine1 is changed just before I call db.SubmitChanges()... SQL Profiler shows only a "reset connection" when the SubmitChanges line executes.  Anyone got a clue why this isn't working?  THANKS!

Answer (score 6):

You can get a quick view of the changes to be submitted using the [GetChangeSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882650.aspx) method.

Also make sure that your table has a primary key defined and that the mapping knows about this primary key. Otherwise you won't be able to perform updates.

Comment: I had no idea that the table needed a primary key.  I was beating my head against a wall for quite a while trying to figure out why the changetracking didn't seem to be working.  Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Funny, to use GetTable and Single. I would have expected the code to look like this:

```
string cstr = ConnectionApi.GetSqlConnectionString("SwDb"); // get connection str
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(cstr)) 
{    
  Address addr = (from a in db.Address where a.Id == id select a).Single();    
  addr.AddressLine1 = colValue.Trim();    
  db.SubmitChanges(); // this seems to have no effect!!!
}
```

I got no idea what GetTable will do to you.

Another thing, for debugging Linq2SQL try adding

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
```

before SubmitChanges(), this will show you the executed SQL.

Comment: db.GetTable<Address>() is the same as db.Address. The latter is just an additional property that calls db.GetTable<>.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks -- your comments will help me sort this out I'm sure! I didn't have the "Id" column defined as the PrimaryKey so that's an obvious non-starter.  I would have expected that LinqToSQL would have thrown an error when the update fails. -- S.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the result.  I can't use the form db.Address, because I didn't use the designer to create my database objects, instead I defined them as classes like this:

```
[Table(Name = "Addresses")]
public class Address
{
    [Column(Name = "Id",IsPrimaryKey=true)]
     public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "AddressLine1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        ...
```

Originally, I didn't have the "Id" column set as PK in the database, nor did I have it identified using IsPrimaryKey=true in the [Column...] specifier above.  BOTH are required!  Once I made that change, the ChangeSet found the update I wanted to do, and did it, but before that it told me that 0 rows needed to be updated and refused to commit the changes.

Thanks for your help!  -- S.

Comment: So the answer was that you needed a primary key defined. :)